# How to call a parent method from a child via ForeignKeyField in peewee?

Tags: python, orm, parent-child, peewee

I have two classes:

```
class A(Base_Model):
    def ping(self):
        print("Ping!")

class B(Base_Model):
    __A_reference = peewee.ForeignKeyField(A, null=True)
    def test_ping(self):
        self.__A_reference.ping()
```

I initialise the database, create both tables and try running `B.test_ping()`, but to no avail.

Have tried changing the way I specify the foreign key to be self-referencing `__A_reference = peewee.ForeignKeyField("self", null=True, backref="Bs")`, but again no use.

Tried looking though a bunch of code examples, but it never seems to be the case that the (child) object that possesses the foreign key is actually using it to call some method from the parent object.

Comment: `.__A_reference` is a `ForeignKeyField` instance, it is hard to expect it will inherit methods of `A` class... is it a part of some larger problem that you are trying to solve? hard to see intent of what you are doing.

Comment: @Evgeny Pogrebnyak I looked in debugger -- and the reference does seem to inheret all of the attributes and methods of A. The bizarre bit is when I look into instance of B itself. It contains three strange attributes: _B.__A_reference: None, _B.__A_reference_id: None and __A_reference: A [pri]. The intended use of __A_reference is veery much like it was a reference to the parent object (analogous to the same use case in C++ or Python); originally the code-base was in-memory only, but we are adding an ORM (peewee) to persist the data in case the server goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this is confusing... accessing B.__A_reference will return the related A instance:

```
In [1]: from peewee import *

In [2]: db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

In [3]: class A(Model):
   ...:     def ping(self):
   ...:         print('ping')
   ...:     class Meta:
   ...:         database = db
   ...:         

In [4]: class B(Model):
   ...:     a = ForeignKeyField(A)
   ...:     class Meta:
   ...:         database = db
   ...:         

In [5]: db.create_tables([A, B])

In [6]: a = A.create()

In [7]: b = B.create(a=a)

In [8]: b.a.ping()
ping
```

Comment: Perhaps it is slightly different way you instantinate `b`, rather than OP. Quite clean cross reference!

Comment: There were some subtle differences in my real-life more complex class structure, but good to know that the overall principle is correct.